# Fast writing to file - Sometimes the file is empty

Tags: java, file-io

**Modification**
After some investigation I can reproduce my problem with this test code. The problem is unrelated to thread but to fast writing :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "Testing fast writing in file";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i++) {
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("temp.txt")));
            bw.write(text);
        } catch(Throwable t) { // Ensure there is no throwable for the test
            System.err.println(t.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if(bw != null) {
                try {
                    bw.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Opening with Notepad++ at different times, I've sometime an empty file.
What would be the best way to avoid this ?

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm analyzing a problem where multiple Threads (can go up to 60) are writing on the same file using `JAXB Marshaller`. Note that the myObject is shared between Threads.

Here is the original code:

```
Marshaller m = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);      
m.marshal(myObject, myFile);
```

The problem is that sometimes when I take a look at the file, it's empty (myObject is never empty nor null). This file allow us to resume some job later if the service crashes.

Thinking the marshalling process could be long I first wrote in a Buffer and then write to the file :

```
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(8192);
marshaller.marshal(myObject, outputStream);
String result = outputStream.toString();
if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
  BufferedWriter bw = null;
  try {
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile));
    bw.write(result);
    bw.flush(); // I know close() should do that, but I tried too
  } catch(IOException ioe) {
    ...
  } finally {
    ... close the bw
  }
```

problem still there. So I also tried to add `synchronized` to the method (the only one used to write to the file) but I've got the same problem.

Finally I also tried to keep a `static boolean` to know if I'm in a writing process:

```
if (!processing) {
  processing = true;
  try {
  Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
  ...
  ... close file writer
  processing = false;
}
```

Same behaviour, what would be the best way to avoid having an empty file ? I'm a bit puzzled on that now.

Comment: Apart from the problem of the empty file, what's your expected output if multiple threads independently write XML text to the same file?

Comment: @Pino Well it's not really important in fact, the resuming can be done whatever Threads write last. But in the end I'll synchronize everything. So my problem is that even synchronized I keep getting some empty files.

Comment: Suggest you look for lost/discarded/ignored exceptions.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I added a -nice- `try{}catch(Throwable)` but never going there, everything is ok.

Comment: Could it be NP++? Perhaps it is silently failing to read the file. Try checking the file size instead of the content.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I checked that it's a beautiful 0k. So it's really empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came with for the moment :
Write in a temp file, once it's done rename it.
The final file is always filled.

```
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.marshal(myObject, myFileTmp);

if (myFileTmp.exists() && myFileTmp.length() > 0) {
  myFile.delete();
  myFileTmp.renameTo(myFile);
}
```

I then modified the code to make only one thread write to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misinterpreting the use of the FileWriter. In the example shown, you write with multiple threads at the same time in the same file, but the way the FileWriter works is that it resets the content of the file unless you explicitly tell it to append.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("temp.txt"), true);
```

If you don't want to append you need to make sure that only one thread is writing to the file. Also inspecting the file which seems empty might just happen to be at the same time that the file get cleared before the writer starts to do his it's job.

Comment: I want to replace not append. `"might just happen to be at the same time that the file get cleared before the writer starts to do his it's job"` yeah exactly and that's what I don't want.